# Getting error during start up of wildfly 10 server

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, jboss, wildfly

I'm getting below error while starting my wildfly10

```
04:21:19,604 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-2) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.module.service."deployment.giftregistry.war".main: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.module.service."deployment.giftregistry.war".main: WFLYSRV0179: Failed to load module: deployment.giftregistry.war:main
        at org.jboss.as.server.moduleservice.ModuleLoadService.start(ModuleLoadService.java:91) [wildfly-server-2.2.0.Final.jar:2.2.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948) [jboss-msc-1.2.6.Final.jar:1.2.6.Final]
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881) [jboss-msc-1.2.6.Final.jar:1.2.6.Final]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [rt.jar:1.8.0_191]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [rt.jar:1.8.0_191]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [rt.jar:1.8.0_191]
Caused by: org.jboss.modules.ModuleNotFoundException: config:main
        at org.jboss.modules.Module.addPaths(Module.java:1093) [jboss-modules.jar:1.5.2.Final]
        at org.jboss.modules.Module.link(Module.java:1449) [jboss-modules.jar:1.5.2.Final]
        at org.jboss.modules.Module.relinkIfNecessary(Module.java:1477) [jboss-modules.jar:1.5.2.Final]
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoader.loadModule(ModuleLoader.java:225) [jboss-modules.jar:1.5.2.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.server.moduleservice.ModuleLoadService.start(ModuleLoadService.java:68) [wildfly-server-2.2.0.Final.jar:2.2.0.Final]
        ... 5 more

04:21:19,618 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "giftregistry.war")]) - failure description: {
    "WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.module.service.\"deployment.giftregistry.war\".main" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.module.service.\"deployment.giftregistry.war\".main: WFLYSRV0179: Failed to load module: deployment.giftregistry.war:main
    Caused by: org.jboss.modules.ModuleNotFoundException: config:main"},
    "WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => ["jboss.module.service.\"deployment.giftregistry.war\".main"],
    "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => undefined
```

Basically I'm migrating my application in AWS. I'm running this server on AWS EC2 instance using docker.I have copy pasted all the configuration present in my last server to this wildfly10 configuratuion.

Comment: Try to build jar with dependencies using maven-assembly-plugin and deploy it

Comment: Can there be any other way around?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved the issue by removing

```
<global-modules>
<module name="config" slot="main"/>
</global-modules>
```

from my standalone.xml

Answer (score 1):

Basically it says that there is a module named *config* missing.

It should be defined in [wildfly-root]/modules/config/main/module.xml together with any needed resources.